# Using Ionic to access ASP.NET Core functionalities

Tags: ionic-framework, asp.net-core, azure-mobile-services, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an asp.net core site with regular controllers (not webapi) and I want to build an ionic mobile app which uses same methods and same authentication as I have registered users.
I host my site as a webapp in azure and i use an sql database.
I don't have a clear vision on how to achieve this but I'm thinking of:

1. Building webapi controllers
2. Building azure mobile service

What option is better and am I missing another option?
Your advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Apps does not support .NET Core at this time.  So the decision is kind of made for you.